# Google Image Search returns no results

Tags: php, search, google-api, google-search

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'MY-KEY');
define('GOOGLE_CX', 'CX-ID');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My Project Name");
$client->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY);
$search = new Google_Service_Customsearch($client);

$params = array(
    'fileType' => 'png',
    'imgSize' => 'large',
    'searchType' => 'image',
    'filter' => 1,
    'num' => 10,
    'googlehost' => 'google.co.nz',
    'cx' => GOOGLE_CX
);

$q = 'lenovo logo transparent';

try {
    $results = $search->cse->listCse($q, $params);
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($results,1).'</pre>';
} catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

echo 'Done!';
```

.. does not return results, nor any errors, just echoes `Done`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `referrer` set for the API was incorrect. I turned it off temporarily and it worked.